# django best approach for creating multiple type users

Tags: python, django

I want to create multiple users in django. I want to know which method will be the best..

```
class Teachers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    .......
```

or should I use..

```
class Teacher(User):
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    .......
```

or I have to make custom user model...
Which will be good on creating multiple type users...??

Comment: Well, its kind of pointless having a field called `is_teacher` when the model itself is called `Teacher`, right? It would make sense if your model was called `User` and then you wanted to set a flag for each user type, but in the code you posted its a bit redundant.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Django doesn't have multiple users - it only has one user and then based on permissions users can do different things.

So, to start off with - there is only one user type in django. If you use the default authentication framework, the model for this user is called `User`, from `django.contrib.auth.models`.

If you want to customize user behavior in django, there are three things you can do:

1. [Customize how you authenticate them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends). By default, authentication is done using a database where passwords are stored. You can authenticate against facebook/google etc. or against your existing user database - for example, with ActiveDirectory if you are on a Windows network.
2. [Create custom permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions), and based on these permissions, restrict what functions users can execute. By default, on every model - django will add basic permissions "can edit", "can delete", "can read". You can create your own and then check if the user has these specific permissions.
3. You can store extra information about the user, along with whatever normally is stored by django. There are two ways to do this, depending on how much customization you need. If everything django provides by default works for you, and all you want to do is store extra information about the user you can [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user) - in previous versions this was called creating a custom profile. The other option you have is to [create your own `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), if you want deeper customization. The most common use of a custom user model is if you want to use an email address as the username.

You don't have to do all three, in fact sometimes all you want to do is store some extra information or have them authenticate using their email address; in some applications you have to modify all three places.

In your case, since all you want to do is store *extra information* about a user, you would need to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user), by creating a model that references `User` (note: you don't inherit from `User`):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Computer Science')
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # .. etc. etc.
```

Comment: What if I want to give different field for teachers and students.. I want to create different model for teacher and student with different field. Only some field are common and they should register with different registration form one for teacher and another for student.

Comment: You don't need to create different models, you just create one model and then in the form that you use to sign up users, you just show the fields that are relevant to them. Don't create multiple models to represent your users, it will create problems later.

Comment: ohk will do same. But I m trying with different model making custom user model. If it dont work I will go with your idea..

Comment: nice and precise answer, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

One approach I was following with Django 1.7 (works with 1.6 too) is to subclass `AbstractUser`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    balance = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
```

To use your model you need to set it to be the one used for authentication in `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.User'
```

Also note that you will now have to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` when referencing
your new `User` model in a relation in your models.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) # ForeignKey(User) will not work
```

Comment: and how to return balance from Transaction... def __unicode__(self): return self.user.balance ??

Comment: Just as with any `ForeignKey` relation.

Comment: Nils, why did you use this approach as oppose to the extending user model?

Comment: @Erika because [you're supposed to subclass `AbstractUser` instead of `User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user).

Comment: @Nils' approach is a good option. It gives a granular control on user permissions at the view level.