# How to use multiple user models in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, django-models

I'm trying to use two user models with different 'username' type each one.

First user type is an administrator who login in with username and password. Second, a customer who login with phone number and password.
Only the customer has custom fields.

I tried customize the Django User model but it only allows one auth user model.

I am thinking use an authentication backend.

Administrator only will login in admin dashboard, while customer only login in application.

Edit.

[Different problem from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841712/django-best-approach-for-creating-multiple-type-users). My user types have different ways to login each other.

My solution: Use Django's user model for dashboard administrator only. Use a Customer model with custom [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django best approach for creating multiple type users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841712/django-best-approach-for-creating-multiple-type-users)

Comment: You can have in your models two user classes that extend from the USER model.

Comment: @raul-castro-rivero any example?

Answer (score 6):

> First user type is an administrator who login in with username and password. Second, a customer who login with phone number and password. Only the customer has custom fields.

You don't want multiple user models (crazy and not really supported in Django anyway). You want [multiple authentication backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends).

Put a User model with a (nullable) phone number field. And add to your application an auth backend which uses phone number + password instead of username + password.

Comment: Yup, I'm thinking about leave phone number null and code an authentication backend (but I also need use JWT with the phone number -_-)