# django model design with different user types

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am just learning Django so I thought of creating a project called job board to understand more in detail. I have drawn the following use case.

- People can register as job seekers, build their profiles and look for
  jobs matching their skillsets
- Companies can register, post jobs.
- Multiple representatives from a company should be able to register
  and post jobs.
- Independent Recruiter can create an account as well.
- The company can contact to that independent recruiter.

How would be the model design for such a use case? I am confused with the multiple user types in Django. Some favors creating a user profile, while some favors using Groups.

For now, I could only do the following

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    '''
      Abstract user because django recommends to start with custom user
    '''
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email Address"), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I could create a model for User and Company. But I have no idea on handling multiple user types like user can be either job seeker or recruiter. Also, multiple representatives from a company should be able to register and post jobs as well as there can be independent recruiter as well. How would you handle such a case if you have to? Can anyone help me in a step by step guide, please? This way it will clear my confusion and will help me in better design of tables in the future.

**Update with example in a nutshell**

```
class User(models.Model):
    '''
        User can be of any 3 types or can have multiple role as well
    '''
    is_job_seeker = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_recruiter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_mentor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) # only user with is_recruiter flag active can be

class JobSeeker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # job seeker profile related fields like experiences, skills, education, profile image etc

class Recruiter(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)
    # recruiter related profile
```

Comment: This is a great question but it's also very broad (not that it's bad, it's just that the answer would be pretty long). Here are two links that look useful and could help in "narrowing down" the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841712/django-best-approach-for-creating-multiple-type-users, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me the path. I would like to check if I correctly understood or not. Can you check the updated section for covering my use cases, please?

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track. @rydber's answers is also nice. One minor thing that I would change is I'd replace the boolean fields with functions/properties checking whether there's a related object present, for instance: `def is_job_seeker(self): try: user.jobseeker; except JobSeeker.DoesNotExist: return False; else: return True`. This way the consistency is improved as there is a single source of truth (but the performance is lower as there's a DB lookup; this can be mitigated by using cached property which is its own can of worms :)). But it's just a nit.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is almost there. It doesn't look like you need a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) right now, so I would just use Django's [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

I would have something like:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # Other company-related fields

class JobSeeker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # Other jobseeker-related fields

class Recruiter(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)
    # Other recruiter-related fields
```

When you create any of the models above, you can assign them a user account; and for recruiter, you can assign the company they work for. For example, a company named stack_overflow can have its own company account with a username/password/etc. Then, recruiters who work for stack_overflow could also have their own accounts with their own username/password/etc. Running a command like `stackoverflow.recruiter_set` will give you all recruiters who work for stack_overflow.

Note that I [do not reference `User` directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model). Using the above approach makes your life easier if you decide to switch User models in the future.

I am assuming you don't want to create a `User`, then create a `Company` and link it to that user - you just want to do it in one go. That's a slightly different question and the solution will involve you creating a sign-up [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/), or something of that sort, where you can add some logic about whether the user is a company, recruiter or jobseeker.

Regarding your other points, it looks like you're looking to set user permissions. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions) are the docs for setting default permissions for your custom users, and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions) are the general docs for Django's built-in permissions system. For example, your Company and Recruiter model could return `True` for `has_perm('your_app.add_job')`, while your Jobseeker model returns `False`. I.e. Companies and Recruiters can create Jobs, but jobseekers cant.

Hope this helps!