# Custom User Model with Multiple User Types vs Django Groups to Handle Logic and Permissions?

Tags: django

### Abstract Question:

If you had multiple users categories with different business logic and permissions, would you use a custom / extended user model with different user types or would you stick with a basic user model and handle differences by means of Django’s groups and group permissions? What are pro’s and con’s? When would you use what way?

### A practical example:

Assuming there is a web application with three different user categories, e.g:

- Applicants
- Recruiters
- Investors

with users in each category also separated into different subgroups with respective permissions - let’s say:

- membership requested
- regular member and
- prime member

How would you go about managing those (overall 9) different user groups and what way would you prefer?

1. Implementing multiple user types in a custom user model (AbstractUser)
2. Sticking with a simple / standard user model and handling different permissions merely by using Django’s build in groups with respective group permissions.
3. A combination of both 1 and 2. (split how?)
4. External package handling permissions (which one?)

Comment: Never user the built-in Django User model directly, even if the built-in Django User implementation fulfill all the requirements of your application.

Comment: Even after having all the roles and permission there maybe chances that authorization is leaking somewhere. What i do is to make custom decorators for common post ,put and patch request and put them in separate files. Always perform penetration testing to verify such.

Comment: extend the AbstractUser model and switch the AUTH_USER_MODEL on your settings.

Comment: @Mr.Robot: Thanks for the advise. I always use a custom model extending AbstractUser. It is recommended and good practice in any case. Still, my question relates more towards how to handle differences in users and their flow and permissions: With a custom user model or by using Django's groups.

Comment: In a former project I used an Auxiliary Model (managed = False) to set global rights and permissions and then assigned users to respective groups with separate rights. Why would I use a custom user model with separate user types instead? Any advantages?

Comment: maybe you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841712/django-best-approach-for-creating-multiple-type-users

Comment: @DiegoAvila: Thanks for the link. I read it. It rather mentions high level options - of which I am aware. Unfortunately, it doesn't clarify when to apply which way. E.g. why would I store different user types in a user model, when I could also use groups to manage / separate permissions? When to use which?

Comment: this is a great answer, the problem "Spanish": https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/953/81846

Comment: @DiegoAvila: A detailed answer indeed. Spanish isn't so much the problem ;-). It seems to be suggested there, to have a basic categorization using Boolean flags on an extended user model plus groups for those handling the permissions. Unfortunately, it is not quite clear to me, why I would need both (the Booleans and the groups) as users could also respectively assigned intro those groups directly, couldn’t they?