# How to implement multiple user types with different roles and permissions in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to web development using Django Framework and Python programming language and I am tasked to make a mini project that implements the following:

1. Permissions Management;
2. Roles Management;
3. Users Accounts Management;
4. Login and Logout; and
5. Password Reset.

What are the appropriate steps for me to accomplish this?

I have read about user authentication and permissions and custom user models but the examples that were given were less complicated than what I actually needed. I have to set up an application that implements multiple user accounts wherein each user can have multiple roles and each roles have different permissions. I know that Django has built-in functions to do this but I want to make my own customization as mush as possible.

I would like to know if creating Custom User Model extending AbstractBaseUser is the best option there is to accomplish this. Also, I would like to know how to customize the Django built-in admin page, such as replacing or deleting unnecessary fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the other workaround except extending AbstractBaseUser is to have another model Profile and relate to it with an [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)
or you can inherit 3 different user models from AbstractBaseUser which is not a good idea
the best answer is to extend AbstractBaseUser 
if default authentication backend and perimissions doesn't suit your needs checkout(which they most likely do!):

[Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django)

[Custom users and permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions)

also checkout:

[django best approach for creating multiple type users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841712/django-best-approach-for-creating-multiple-type-users)

[How to Implement Multiple User Types with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)

--UPDATE--

and if you want to have different permission groups checkout:

[Permissions and Authorization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

[Groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#groups)

`django.contrib.auth.models.Group` models are a generic way of categorizing users so you can apply permissions, or some other label, to those users. A user can belong to any number of groups.

A user in a group automatically has the permissions granted to that group. For example, if the group Site editors has the permission `can_edit_home_page`, any user in that group will have that permission.

Comment: Is there a way wherein the user (e.g. admin) can create a permission in the admin page? Like he/she can create a new permission - input permission name, its description, and choose if its active or inactive?

Comment: ofcourse there is, read django groups docs:
[Permissions and Authorization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) and also [Groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#groups)

Comment: @Semb i updated the post with more information about your question