# Is it a django rest framework good practise?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, authorization

I am developing a restaurant management system where there are 4 types of user : admin, chef, driver (who delivers food) and the customer, and i am using django rest framework to create my restful api.

Howeve I am stuck at the authentication process, since django doesn't have multiple users, i've read a lot of tutorials and stackoverflow questions and answers including :

- [How to implement multiple user types with different roles and permissions in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507250/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-different-roles-and-permissions-in-dja?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to Implement Multiple User Types with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)
- [django best approach for creating multiple type users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841712/django-best-approach-for-creating-multiple-type-users)
- [Creating multiple user types and using proxy models](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-multiple-user-types-and-using-proxy-models-in-python-django/)

I didn't want to use the proxy model, since i didn't want to violate django rule for no multiple users, so i've created my solution but i want to know if it is good or bad or violate some good practises and if it will cause me headaches in the Future.

## models.py file :

```py
class UserRoles(models.TextChoices):
    ADMIN = 'admin', 'Admin'
    CUSTOMER = 'customer', 'Customer'
    CHEF = 'chef', 'Chef'
    DRIVER = 'driver', 'Driver'

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=UserRoles.choices)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_chef = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_driver = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin


class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    email_restaurant = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    address_restaurant = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number_restaurant = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    address_url = models.URLField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name

# ... 
# chef model and driver model are the same as Customer model
```

## serializers.py file :

```py
class UserAuthenticationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # for authentication of four users
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'role', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {"id": {"read_only": True}, "password": {"write_only": True}}
   
    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop("password", None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # for delete, retrive and update users
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {"id": {"read_only": True}}


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # for performing tasks only on customers
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {"user": {"read_only": True}}

# ... chef and driver serializers are similar to Customer serializer
```

## views.py file :

```py
class UserSignUpView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    # create user
    def post(self, request, role):
        request.data['role'] = role
        serializer = UserAuthenticationSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            instance = serializer.save()
            user = User.objects.get(id=instance.id)

            if role == UserRoles.ADMIN:
                user.is_admin = True
                Admin.objects.create(user_id=user.id)   # the instance get stored in Admin table too 
            elif role == UserRoles.CUSTOMER:
                user.is_customer = True
                Customer.objects.create(user_id=user.id)
            elif role == UserRoles.CHEF:
                user.is_chef = True
                Chef.objects.create(user_id=user.id)
            else:
                user.is_driver = True
                Driver.objects.create(user_id=user.id)
            user.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class UserSignInView(TokenObtainPairView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = TokenObtainPairSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = User.objects.get(email=request.data['email'])
            user_serializer = UserAuthenticationSerializer(instance=user)
            serializer.validated_data['user'] = user_serializer.data
            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class UserSignOutView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    # put user refresh token to the black list
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            if "refresh_token" not in request.data:
                raise RequiredRequestDataField("refresh_token")

            refresh_token = request.data["refresh_token"]
            token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
            token.blacklist()
            return Response(
                messages["user_logout"], status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT
            )

        except RequiredRequestDataField as r:
            print(r)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class AdminProfileView(APIView):
    # view for retrieving admin information to put them on his/her profile

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]

    # update admin information
    def put(self, request, pk):
        if not "last_name" in request.data:
            raise RequiredRequestDataField("last_name")
        if not "first_name" in request.data:
            raise RequiredRequestDataField("first_name")
        if not "email" in request.data:
            raise RequiredRequestDataField("email")
        if not "email_restaurant" in request.data:
            raise RequiredRequestDataField("email_restaurant")
        if not "address_restaurant" in request.data:
            raise RequiredRequestDataField("address_restaurant")
        if not "phone_number_restaurant" in request.data:
            raise RequiredRequestDataField("phone_number_restaurant")
        
        admin_data = {}
        admin_data['email_restaurant'] = request.data['email_restaurant']
        admin_data['address_restaurant'] = request.data['address_restaurant']
        admin_data['phone_number_restaurant'] = request.data['phone_number_restaurant']

        user_data = {}
        user_data['last_name'] = request.data['last_name']
        user_data['first_name'] = request.data['first_name']
        user_data['email'] = request.data['email']

        admin_serializer = AdminSerializer(data=admin_data, instance=Admin.objects.get(user=pk))
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data, instance=User.objects.get(id=pk))
        if admin_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) and user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            admin_serializer.save()
            user_serializer.save()
            response = {
                "id": pk,
                **user_data,
                **admin_data
            }
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        else:
            return Response(admin_serializer.errors or user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # retrieve admin information
    def get(self, request, pk):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
            admin = Admin.objects.get(user=user)
            response = {
                "id": pk,
                "first_name": admin.user.first_name,
                "last_name": admin.user.last_name,
                "email": admin.user.email,
                "email_restaurant": admin.email_restaurant,
                "phone_number_restaurant" : admin.phone_number_restaurant,
                "address_restaurant": admin.address_restaurant
            }
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                {"details": "Admin account does not exist."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

# ....
```

Even though everything works fine but i want to know if i am doing it wrong. Please any suggestions to improve my code for more code structure or readability would be highly approciated.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your effort to do all this stuff but for example, in future, Your restaurant management would increase then how can you manage all these stuff

1. Permission
2. Roles
3. Users

So you have to make it separate permissions and create model for Custom
Roles that does not effect on your BE(Backend) and that's good practice to keep separate things.

**Permission**

You can manage permission to create json file and define by default creating two roles like Admin or HR or what name you want to give and you will define which api's Admin or HR can access and call these permission in your API's

**Role**

Role might be Admin or superuse and HR and sub-HR(these are dynamic you can restric them to acees API's)

so you can manage all these stuff like this it's good practice to make all things separately.
if you did'n get any point you can feel free to ask me.

Comment: I got it, I should add permissions to user roles. Could you provide me with link or tell me the best way to do that ?

Comment: https://github.com/tanveer-ahmad74/Permission...... 
https://github.com/tanveer-ahmad74/ExceptionDRF

Comment: That's a detailed project, thanks.

Comment: you are welcome brother these project recently I made if you find any difficulty feel free to ask me