# How to prevent user to be both of types?

Tags: django, django-users

I have a model like from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25842236/11486181):

```py
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Is it possible to prevent create new user both of types simultaneously at model level? In other words, it could be ONLY `is_student == False` and `is_teacher == True` or vise versa.

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to accomplish?
Do you want to create multiple users but with different fields, or?

Comment: @LauritsL.L., yes, something like this. I need to create multiple users, but each user can be only teacher or only student. They have one different field, but as in referenced answer's comments mentioned, I don't need to create different models. So I think I need to create one model with both of fields and set it to NULL if field don't relate to user, isn't it?

Comment: If they’re mutually exclusive, then just make *one* field `role` which can be either “teacher” or “student”!?

Comment: You could override the save method but really you should have a role field, you're only one feature away from `is_examiner` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you *can't* have multiple User models with different properties.
Django can only have one User model.
If the only change you need is that one of the fields need to be gone, my best bet would be to just ignore the field when you need to.
For example, when a student wants to sign up they click on a "Sign up as a student" link, where you just omit the `is_teacher` field from the form and vice versa when it is a teacher.

An example of this could be:

**User model**:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""
    username = models.CharField(max_length=75, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the user."""
        string_repr = str(self.username) + ' (' + str(self.email) + ')'

        return string_repr
```

**UserCreationForm model (for both student and teacher):**

```
class CreateUserStudentForm(UserCreationForm):
    # Require the email field.
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email", "username", "is_student", "password1", "password2")

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        return data.lower()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # Get all the relevant data, and save it.
        user.email = self.clean_email()
        user.username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        user.is_student = self.cleaned_data["is_student"]
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        # Save the newly created user.
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class CreateUserTeacherForm(UserCreationForm):
    # Require the email field.
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email", "username", "is_teacher", "password1", "password2")

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        return data.lower()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # Get all the relevant data, and save it.
        user.email = self.clean_email()
        user.username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        user.is_teacher = self.cleaned_data["is_teacher"]
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        # Save the newly created user.
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I understood it is not possible to validate it in model level?

Comment: @PavelAntspovich No, that is not possible, as Django can only be used with one user model. But forms should do the job. :)

Comment: @The thing is my app is RESTFUL and forms wouldn't be controlled by me (as I'm understanding REST pattern for now). I'll get an option with role field as guys above mentioned. But anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: @PavelAntspovich Okay. Hope I was a little helpful. :)