# How to Implement Multiple User Types with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I want to create a Django model like

```
user_types = (("Agent", "Agent"), ("Branch", "Branch"), ("Company", "Company"))

class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=user_types, blank=False)
```

and if user define user_type to store these field data
 there should come some extra field like:

```
   if user_type is Agent then:
        agent_code
        agent_name
    if user_type is Branch then:
        Branch_code
        Branch_name
        Branch_Id
    if user_type is Company then:
        Company_code
        Company_name
        Company_Id
```

Is there any good way to handle this model?

or I have to define all required fields in different modelsClass and inherent that class User class.

like:

```
class ReqData(models.Model):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=user_types, blank=False)
    agent_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    branch_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    branch_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    ....
    ....


class User(models.Model, ReqData):
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: The question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25842236/6749313

Comment: I think a possible solution to your problem would be to create a model class for each user type with their respective extra fields and a OneToOneField to the user model.